# Cross-compile OMXPlayer

Tags: omxplayer

I would like to cross-compile OMXPlayer, ultimately so that I can implement playlist support for personal use. Don't bother telling me that that is an unrealistic goal. Perhaps I can help out with the project in other ways.

I'm having difficulty establishing a proper build environment. Running Ubuntu Lucid host, targeting a raspbian based distro.

Links to how someone has done this, recently, would be helpful. Could exchange email addresses and PM for a while, with the goal of me writing a guide. I don't know how to contact popcornmix....

Comment: Why would you need to cross compile omxplayer? Could you not implement this in a shell script?

Comment: Using a shell script, separate files are played with different processes of OMXPlayer.

This means that I cannot use keybindings within OMXPlayer to navigate through a playlist.

Using a shell script, I can quit the current OMXPlayer process and it will continue on to the next file in the playlist, but I would never be able to go backward without some complicated workarounds. OMXPlayer will accept Ctrl-C and terminate, but I have to hit it multiple times with questionable reliability in order to quit out of OMXPlayer AND the shell script.

Comment: I imagine that most people would prefer to cross-compile if they knew how, rather than try and compile something on the pi.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done on a Debian / Ubuntu environment. Personally I set up a VM running Debian.

Now if you choose debian, run:

```
sudo apt-get install debootstrap qemu-user-static
```

If ubuntu, run:

```
sudo apt-get install debootstrap qemu-debootstrap
```

Now, run:

```
git clone https://github.com/skgsergio/rpi-buildenv.git
cd rpi-buildenv
./install.sh
./prepare_omxplayer.sh
./build.sh
```

However at some point after compiling ffmpeg (during omxplayer compilation, which is quite short) the script will fail. Then run:

```
cd /root/omxplayer-build/omxplayer-src/
./prepare-native-raspbian.sh
# prepare-native told me to run the following command, you may not have to
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libva1 libidn11-dev libssl1.0-dev
make
make dist
```

This will finally create ./omxplayer-src/omxplayer.bin

Please note that my raspberry pi 1 running jessie also needed "libswscale.so" to run omxplayer.bin, which I then copied from "/rpi-buildenv/rootfs/root/omxplayer-build/omxplayer-src/ffmpeg_compiled/usr/local/lib/libswscale.so" to "/lib/libswscale.so" on my raspberry. Then I run `sudo ldconfig` to updated the libraries.

I really want to thank skgsergio for his script. It would have been way harder without him!